# How to set an item's email/phone in PodioKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, podio

Using PodioKit (2.0.0 on OSX) i'm struggling to create a new item with an email/phone field populated.

It wants a string for the field (or it throws an exception) but giving it an email as a string I get a 400 error.

In Podio the field can be tagged as what sort of email/phone it is, such as home, work, other etc. so I'm not sure how to specify the email/phone correctly. I can't see any special classes like PKTContactInfo or anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PodioKit remains a work-in-progress, and unfortunately the Email field isn't yet supported explicitly in the model layer or the `PKTItem` convenience methods.  Until the SDK can be improved to support such features, you can work around this limitation using `PKTItemsApi`'s `requestToCreateItemInApp` method and building up the parameters for the request yourself.

**Creating an Item with Email Field - PodioKit 2.0**

Here's an example of creating an Item in an App with only a Title and Email field (Swift 3.0):

```
let valueDictionary:[String:String] = ["type":"work", "value":"test@podio.com"]
let fieldDictionary:[String:Any] = ["email":valueDictionary, "title":"r3-d6"]

let createItemRequest = PKTItemsAPI.requestToCreateItemInApp(withID: 17206313, fields: fieldDictionary, files: nil, tags: nil)

PKTClient.current().perform(createItemRequest).onComplete { response, error in
  if error == nil {
    print("Save successful!")
  } else {
    print("Error saving new item.")
  }
}
```

As you noted in your question, the `type` of an email field can be any of the following values: `home`, `work`, `other`.

If your item is more complex and you don't want to manually insert all of the fields, you could create the item using the convenience methods and then update the item's email field similar to the example above.

**Edit: Updating existing Item with email field - PodioKit 2.0**

To update an existing item, you can use `PKTItemsAPI` method `requestToUpdateItemWithID`.  Note that this request requires the Item ID, whereas to the create item requests require an App ID:

```
let valueDictionary:[String:String] = ["type":"work", "value":"updatetest@test.info"]
let fieldDictionary:[String:Any] = ["email":valueDictionary, "title":"r5-d5"]

let updateItemRequest = PKTItemsAPI.requestToUpdateItem(withID: 383626238, fields: fieldDictionary, files: nil, tags: nil)

PKTClient.current().perform(updateItemRequest).onComplete { response, error in
  if error == nil {
    print("Completed update!")
  } else {
    print("Error updating item.")
  }
}
```

Comment: tsk tsk for an SDK version of 2.0.0 with incomplete functionality, but yay for quick community response!

Can you show how to edit an item that's been created with the convenience methods? I can't seem to figure that bit out as anything I try causes exceptions as it's expecting the email field to be a string rather than a dictionary.

Comment: So you won't be able to create or update an Item's email field with the convenience methods on `PKTItem`.  Those methods rely on an underlying model layer that maps each field type to its expected values - and the Email field is not supported (you can see the supported fields here: http://podio.github.io/podio-objc/fields/).  What you can do is create your item, and then use `PKTItemsAPI` to create an update request -- I'll add some example code to the answer above, but it is nearly identical to the example provided.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth, I thought you meant you could create an item with the convenience methods and then before sending it to the API fudge in the email but I see you mean it would require two steps. All working ok though as is so many thanks for the help!

Comment: Sure thing.  Sorry for the confusion, and happy coding!